# Is there any way to add a abstract method for JPA repository : findByEnumContaining(String enum) [enum is subString for possible ENUM values]

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

This is my JPA @Repository, here we can get `list<Person>` with `findByFullNameContaining(String query)` - by providing just substring of fullName in query

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,String> {
    Optional<Person> findByFullName(String fullName);
    List<Person> findByDepartment(Department department);
    List<Person> findByFullNameContaining(String query);
    
}
```

Similarly, Can we perform something for ENUM values - by providing sub-string value of ENUM? How?

Eg.

```
public enum Department {
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    EAST,
    WEST
}
```

`List<Person> findByDepartmentContaining(String query);`

JPA @Entity Person:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id 
    @NotNull(message = "Mobile number is required")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10, message = "Mobile no. must be 10 digits")
    @Column(name = "person_id", unique = true, length = 10)
    private String mobileNum;

    @Transient
    @NotNull(message = "Password is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "Password cannot be empty")
    private String password="****";

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be empty")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255, message = "fullName must be 1-255 characters long")
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "department")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull(message = "Department must be specified")
    private Department department = Department.UNKNOWN;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String mobileNum, String fullName, String password, Department department) {
        this.mobileNum = mobileNum;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getMobileNum() {
        return mobileNum;
    }

    public void setMobileNum(String mobileNum) {
        this.mobileNum = mobileNum;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [fullName=" + fullName + ", mobileNum=" + mobileNum + ", password=" + password + ", department=" + department + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show me your entity Person model ?

Comment: Hi @A.khalifa, added a Person entity in question.

Answer (score 2):

The question does not specify what exactly the issue is when declaring such a method.

But having tried with `spring boot 2.7` with `PostgreSql` Database the application throws the following runtime error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%some value%] did not match expected type [com.Department (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
```

The issue at least with hibernate is that it will expect a Department field in an entity to be always passed as parameter in it's own object type which is `Department`.

I don't think there is a way to avoid this, as this is an out of the box functionality for Hibernate.

I think however that the correct approach would not be to define this type of method but the following. `Department` already exists in application code so it is known at the time the query needs to be invoked. So I think that the following solution would be considered a better practice:

```
//Repository method to be used in PersonRepository
List<Person> findByDepartmentIn(List<Department> departments);
```

And then the repository could be invoked in the following way from the service layer.

```
//Service method to be used
public List<Person> findByDepartmentIn(String searchBy) {

    List<Department> departments = Arrays.stream(Department.values()).filter(dep -> dep.getName().contains(searchBy)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return personRepository.findDepartmentIn(departments);
}
```